# RabbitMQ on Ubuntu 10.04 Server

Tags: ubuntu, rabbitmq, ubuntu-10.04

Trying to run RabbitMQ on VPS with Ubuntu 10.04. Doing everything like usual:

- added RabbitMQ deb repo
- updated with apt-get update
- installed with apt-get install rabbitmq-server

On my local machine with Ubuntu 11.10 and another VPS with same 10.04 everything works just fine. But on this one i getting error like this (from /var/log/rabbitmq/startup_log):

```
    Activating RabbitMQ plugins ...

********************************************************************************
********************************************************************************

0 plugins activated:

ERROR: epmd error for host "67714": badarg (unknown POSIX error)
```

What i'm doing wrong and wtf is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following worked for me on Fedora 16, thanks to an [anonymous hint](http://codingiscoding.wordpress.com/2011/04/17/rabbitmq-on-os-x/).

```
su
    vim /etc/hosts
        127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain   localhost  YOUR-HOSTNAME
        ::1       localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6
    service rabbitmq-server start
```

For example, suppose your hostname is 67714.

```
su
    vim /etc/hosts
        127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain   localhost  67714
        ::1       localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6
    service rabbitmq-server start
```

Answer (score 15):

This worked for me on CentOS 5.8 when I was unable to use the /etc/hosts file to fix it:

1. Create a rabbitmq environment variables config file at /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf
2. Add NODENAME=rabbit@localhost to it (note that just localhost didn't work)
3. sudo service rabbitmq-server start

To see more about config options, check this out: http://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html#customise-general-unix-environment.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and was able to solve it simply by removing a numerical HOSTNAME that I was using and replacing it with a normal alphabetic word for example: my hostname was **1989** and i replaced it with **tadiwa**